# Breakpoint with Condition

Tags: c++, qt, dbg

Is there a way how to set up more complex condition for breakpoints in QtCreator? (dbg) At least comparing the QStrings, but other complex type would be nice too. Integer comparing like in tutorials works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the breakpoint (red ball in the left hand side of the text editor) and select something like "Edit breakpoint". A dialog then let you put conditions on the breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: Nice, but how are you using this for comparing for example strings? Let's say I have function `void foo(QString bar){...}` and would like to pause when bar == "BAR"?

Comment: HAve you tried to put `bar == "BAR"` in the condition field?

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Sometimes. Probably some bug somewhere. Like the breakpoint sometimes duplicates.

Comment: @LiborTomsik: Conditions are limited to function without any side-effects (from debugger point of view). You may have to use internal data instead of getter/methods.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+click or right click a breakpoint and choose Edit Breakpoint.

A window comes up where you can set "Condition" and how many times it should be ignored before the debugger stops the execution.

The condition can be whatever you would write in a conditional c++ clause.

There are other options as well such as which thread are you targeting.

Comment: condition should not have side effect, whereas `if (side_effect())` is legal.